# Check for Empty result of SelectTokens json query

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I would like to check for Empty or null result of the SelectTokens query, it returns empty when there is no 'RunnerNo' in the (badly constructed) json; works perfectly otherwise.

```
  Dim readingJson = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(JsonString)
  Dim aRunnerInfos = New List(Of Linq.JToken)

  aRunnerInfos = readingJson.SelectTokens("$.runners[?(@.RunnerNo == " & H.Item("No").ToString & ")]", True)
```

I have tried: If aRunnerInfos Is Nothing, and several other variants but all fails.

EDIT:
I have tried .count

```
 If aRunnerInfos.Count() = 0 Then
                            Stop  
    End If
```

returns: "Public member 'Count' on type 'd__4' not found."

Comment: How do you people work without data types!  Please add data types to your variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```vb
Dim readingJson = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(JsonString)
Dim aRunnerInfos = New List(Of Linq.JToken)

aRunnerInfos = readingJson.SelectTokens("$.runners[?(@.RunnerNo == " & H.Item("No").ToString & ")]", True)
```

Updated code:

```vb
Dim readingJson = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(JsonString)
Dim aRunnerInfos as IEnumerable(Of Linq.JToken)

aRunnerInfos = readingJson.SelectTokens("$.runners[?(@.RunnerNo == " & H.Item("No").ToString & ")]", True)

If aRunnerInfos.Count = 0 Then
    'Do stuff
Else
    'Do other stuff
End If
```

Alternate:

```vb
Dim readingJson = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(JsonString)
Dim aRunnerInfos as Linq.JToken

aRunnerInfos = readingJson.SelectTokens("$.runners[?(@.RunnerNo == " & H.Item("No").ToString & ")]", True)

If aRunnerInfos Is Nothing Then
    'Do stuff
Else
    'Do other stuff
End If
```

Comment: thank you, I have tried .count before, it returns with "Public member 'Count' on type '<ExecuteFilter>d__4' not found."

Comment: Is that path suppose to return an `IEnumerable(Of JToken)` or simply a `JToken`?

Comment: I believe IEnumerable(Of JToken), but my skill level is not great, the above was all constructed from web examples and while it works I don't quite fully understand the inner workings. Hence being forced to ask, and without datatypes.

Comment: Change your list to an IEnumerable if a list is indeed being returned. I also added an alternate option for if the returned object is actually a single JToken entity.